# Find the conserved quantity

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives, dynamical-systems

I have the system of ode $\frac{da}{dt}=2ab$,
$\frac{db}{dt}=b^2-a^2+1-\frac{a}{\pi}$

When I am plotting it in xppaut(see the picture attached). I can see that a quantity is conserved but I am unable to figure out the expression. Can anyone please help? If you can give me the steps on how you get the conserved quantity that would be very helpful as well.

**My try:** I was using trial and error with $\alpha a^2+\beta b^2$ but didn't get much help.
Now I am trying to find out the integrating factor of $\frac{da}{db}=\frac{2ab}{b^2-a^2+1-\frac{a}{\pi}} \Rightarrow (b^2-a^2+1-\frac{a}{\pi})da-(2ab)db=0$.
Now this is not exact[$2b\neq -2b$].

Then I got the integrating factor $=\frac{1}{a^2}$ and got the solution
$$\frac{b^2}{a}+\frac{1}{a}+a+\frac{\ln a}{\pi}=C$$ for some integrating constant $C$.

Now I am trying to use it somehow. If you get a conserved quantity please let me know.[image]

Comment: The expression $\frac{b^2}{a} + \frac{1}{a} + a + \frac{\ln a}{\pi}$ is the conserved quantity. What else are you asking?

Comment: Could you give references to xppaut ?

Comment: Yes I got that later on.

Comment: @JeanMarie what are "references to xppaut"? I haven't done that before. So I was not aware.

Comment: I mean : you have mentionned and used a software called "xppaut". My question was "could you give some information about this software" ?

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(b^2-a^2+1-\frac{a}{\pi}\right)da-(2ab)db=0$$
$$\implies b^2da-(2ab)db=\left(a^2+\frac{a}{\pi}-1\right)da$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{\left(\frac{a}{b^2}\right)^2}d\left(\frac{a}{b^2}\right)=\frac{1}{a^2}\left(a^2+\frac{a}{\pi}-1\right)da$$
$$\implies \frac{b^2}{a}+\frac{1}{a}+a+\frac{\ln a}{\pi}=C$$
Since $C$ is independent of the variable $t$, it is a conserved quantity.

Comment: Hasn't this result already been obtained by Ri-Li ?